# Tuples in unwanted alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

In Python 3 I have a program coded as below. It basically takes an input from a user and checks it against a list of tuples (EXCHANGE_DATA) and outputs a list of information. The problem is, is that the data has been sorted alphabetically when it is outputted and this is not the way I want it. How do I fix it?

```
from shares import EXCHANGE_DATA
portfolio_str=input("Please list portfolio: ")
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.replace(' ','')
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.upper()
portfolio_list= portfolio_str.split(',')
print()
print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8}'.format('Code', 'Name', 'Price'))
for code, share_name, share_value in EXCHANGE_DATA:
  if code in portfolio_list:
        print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value))
```

Example input:
`GPG,HNZ,DIL,FRE`

The output should be as follows:

```
Please list portfolio: GPG,HNZ,DIL,FRE

Code  Name                   Price
GPG   Guinnesspeat            2.32
HNZ   Heartland Nz            3.85
DIL   Diligent                5.30
FRE   Freightway              6.71
```

but I get:

```
Please list portfolio: GPG,HNZ,DIL,FRE

Code   Name                    Price
DIL    Diligent                 5.30
FRE    Freightway               6.71
GPG    Guinnesspeat             2.32
HNZ    Heartland Nz             3.85
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
from shares import EXCHANGE_DATA
portfolio_str=input("Please list portfolio: ")
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.replace(' ','')
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.upper()
portfolio_list= portfolio_str.split(',')
print()
print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8}'.format('Code', 'Name', 'Price'))
EXCHANGE_DATA = {code:(share_name,share_value) for code, share_name, share_value in EXCHANGE_DATA}
for code in portfolio_list:
     share_name, share_value = EXCHANGE_DATA[code]
     print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value))
```

Comment: The problem is that you're looping over the entries in `EXCHANGE_DATA`, and those are sorted alphabetically. You should instead loop over the entries in `portfolio_list` and use those to look up values in `EXCHANGE_DATA`. See @NPE's answer for code.

Comment: @IgnisErus I've added in his code now I get `builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` for the second line, is there something else I need to add in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to turn `EXCHANGE_DATA` into a dictionary, using `code` as the key. Then you'll be able to transform your loop like:

```
for code in portfolio_list:
    share_name, share_value = EXCHANGE_DATA[code]
    print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, share_name, share_value))
```

Comment: I've removed the : but now I get an error:
`builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` also for the second line

Comment: @jevans -- "One way is to **turn EXCHANGE_DATA into a dictionary**, using code as the key. "

Comment: now I get `builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required`

Comment: @jevans: Change `code:{share_name:share_value}` to `code:(share_name,share_value)`

Comment: Ok its working now but I need a way to handle the fact that if I enter something that's not in the dictionary- i.e. KeyError